# Uso Correctamente del ListView en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, app

Hola resulta que quiero poner varias recetas una al lado de la otra y que se pueda hacer scroll horizontal he tratado diferente forma y ninguna me ha funcionado y hay entrar un ListView dentro de un Row me da un **ERROR de PIXELES**  dejare capturas de pantallas Espero que alguien me ayude por favor.
[image: Imagen Del Problema que me sucedio]

```
import 'package:recetas_rusas/src/pages/home_page.dart';
//import 'package:recetas_rusas/src/pages/recetas_categorias.dart';
//import 'package:recetas_rusas/src/pages/variables.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Recetas',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Recetas'),
            ),
            body: HomePage1()));
  }
}

class HomePage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Categorias de recetas',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            )
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                  )
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              width: 150,
              height: 290,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipOval(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://www.comedera.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/ensalada-rusa-1-1024x800.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Ensaladas',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Deliciosas recetas de ensalada',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '250 Kcal',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                  )
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              width: 150,
              height: 290,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipOval(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://www.comedera.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/ensalada-rusa-1-1024x800.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Ensaladas',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Deliciosas recetas de ensaladas',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '250 Kcal',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                  )
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              width: 150,
              height: 290,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipOval(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://www.comedera.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/ensalada-rusa-1-1024x800.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Ensaladas',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Deliciosas recetas de ensaladas de ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '250 Kcal',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

la idea de tras de este proyecto es hacer una app de receta
y subirla a la Play Store.

ListView es el widget de desplazamiento más utilizado. Muestra sus hijos uno tras otro en la dirección de desplazamiento. En el eje transversal, se requiere que los niños llenen el ListView.

Si no es nulo, itemExtent fuerza a los hijos a tener la extensión dada en la dirección de desplazamiento. Especificar un itemExtent es más eficiente que dejar que los niños determinen su propia extensión porque la maquinaria de desplazamiento puede hacer uso del conocimiento previo de la extensión de los niños para ahorrar trabajo, por ejemplo, cuando la posición de desplazamiento cambia drásticamente.

Hay cuatro opciones para construir un ListView:

El constructor predeterminado toma una List  explícita de hijos. Este constructor es apropiado para vistas de lista con una pequeña cantidad de hijos porque la construcción de la Lista requiere hacer un trabajo para cada hijo que posiblemente podría mostrarse en la vista de lista en lugar de solo aquellos hijos que son realmente visibles.

El constructor ListView.builder toma un IndexedWidgetBuilder, que crea los elementos secundarios a pedido. Este constructor es apropiado para vistas de lista con un número grande (o infinito) de hijos porque el constructor se llama solo para aquellos hijos que son realmente visibles.

El constructor ListView.separated toma dos IndexedWidgetBuilders: itemBuilder construye elementos secundarios a pedido, y separatorBuilder construye de manera similar elementos secundarios separadores que aparecen entre los elementos secundarios. Este constructor es apropiado para vistas de lista con un número fijo de hijos.

El constructor ListView.custom toma un SliverChildDelegate, que brinda la capacidad de personalizar aspectos adicionales del modelo secundario. Por ejemplo, SliverChildDelegate puede controlar el algoritmo utilizado para estimar el tamaño de los niños que no son realmente visibles.

Para controlar el desplazamiento de desplazamiento inicial de la vista de desplazamiento, proporcione un controlador con su conjunto de propiedades ScrollController.initialScrollOffset.

De forma predeterminada, ListView rellenará automáticamente los extremos desplazables de la lista para evitar obstrucciones parciales indicadas por el relleno de MediaQuery. Para evitar este comportamiento, reemplace con una propiedad de relleno cero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola podrías utilizar:

```
SizedBox(
   height: 250.0,
   ListView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: []
   ),
)
```

Pero elimina la Fila `Row` y usa `scrollDirection`, además asegúrate de darle un alto fijo envolviendo la lista con `SizedBox`, `Container`, `ConstrainedBox`, etc.

Para mejor performance de la app si tienes varias recetas, podrías crear un archivo .json y despues generar una lista utilizando el constructor `ListView.builder` bajo demanda, o a su vez podrías crear una lista de los widgets `List<Widget>`y pasarle al constructor bajo demanda.

```
ListView.builder(
   physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   itemCount: recipes.length,
   itemBuilder: (_, index) {
      return RecipeCard(recipe: recipes[index]);
   },
);
```

Comment: gracias me subaste